# Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler

Tags: laravel-5

[RuntimeException]  Elasticsearch-PHP requires cURL, or a custom HTTP handler.

How to solve this problem in laravel 5.

Comment: https://github.com/shift31/laravel-elasticsearch have a look at this

Answer (score 5):

Do you have php curl installed on your machine? installing `php5-curl` might fix it.
Quote from the elastic search website: 'ext-curl: the Libcurl extension for PHP is required'

Comment: Worked like a charm. Dont forget to restart Apache when you install the module. I have PHP 7, so i used "php-curl" instead of "php5-curl".